# Typescript seemingly not resolving undefined correctly

Tags: typescript, types

In the following code I expect the API payload to contain either a `shareholderCompany` or a `shareholderExternalPerson` and whichever one resolves as being true will trigger a function call as seen below. For some reason it seems to think in the child function that the `shareholderCompany` is undefined.

```
export const upsert = async(serviceData: any, companyShareholder: CompanyShareholdersDefinitionInterface, { transaction }: any) => {
    const { shareholderCompany, shareholderExternalPerson } = companyShareholder;

    if (shareholderCompany) {
        return upsertCompanyShareholderCompany(serviceData, companyShareholder, { transaction });
    }
    if (shareholderExternalPerson) {
        return upsertCompanyShareholderPerson(serviceData, companyShareholder, { transaction });
    }
}

export const upsertCompanyShareholderCompany = async(serviceData: any, companyShareholder: CompanyShareholdersDefinitionInterface, { transaction }: any) => {
    const { company_id, source, class: shareholderClass, shareholderCompany } = companyShareholder;
    // Says that shareholderCompany might be undefined
```

These are the types:

```
export type CompanyShareholdersDefinitionInterface = CompanyShareholdersCompanyInterface | CompanyShareholdersExternalPersonInterface;

interface CompanyShareholdersCompanyInterface {
    shareholderCompany: CompanyDefinitionInterface,
    shareholderExternalPerson?: ExternalPersonDefinitionInterface
}

interface CompanyShareholdersExternalPersonInterface {
    shareholderCompany?: CompanyDefinitionInterface,
    shareholderExternalPerson: ExternalPersonDefinitionInterface
}
```

What am I missing here that's causing it to complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `upsertCompanyShareholderCompany` definition, you are telling TypeScript that `companyShareholder` is `CompanyShareholdersDefinitionInterface`, which is *either* `CompanyShareholdersCompanyInterface` or `CompanyShareholdersExternalPersonInterface`, the latter of which has an optional `shareholderCompany`, so it *can* be undefined.

I think `companyShareholder` should be type `CompanyShareholdersCompanyInterface` instead:

```
export const upsertCompanyShareholderCompany = async(serviceData: any, companyShareholder: CompanyShareholdersCompanyInterface, { transaction }: any) => {
    const { shareholderCompany } = companyShareholder;
    // Always CompanyDefinitionInterface
}
```

Which moves the problem up to your `upsert` function because you can't invoke `upsertCompanyShareholderCompany` with a `companyShareholder` of type `CompanyShareholdersDefinitionInterface`. You can introduce a typeguard that will narrow it:

```
function isCompanyShareholdersCompany(inp: CompanyShareholdersDefinitionInterface): inp is CompanyShareholdersCompanyInterface{
    return !!inp.shareholderCompany;
}
```

Which would make your `upsert` function look something like this:

```
export const upsert = async(serviceData: any, companyShareholder: CompanyShareholdersDefinitionInterface, { transaction }: any) => {
    if (isCompanyShareholdersCompany(companyShareholder)) {
        // companyShareholder is of CompanyShareholdersCompanyInterface type
        return upsertCompanyShareholderCompany(serviceData, companyShareholder, { transaction });
    }
    
    // companyShareholder can only be CompanyShareholdersExternalPersonInterface now
    return upsertCompanyShareholderPerson(serviceData, companyShareholder, { transaction });
}
```